# Visual Studio Code - Five Server - preview not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the "Five Server" extension by Yannick (v0.2.39).
I have an index.html and script.js file.
The problem is that when I work on script.js, Five Server doesn't update the actual webpage.
Instead, it shows a page with the JavaScript code visible.
I'm using Google Chrome as my default browser.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks for the help!